# Why this question is unclear?

Tags: discussion

[What other units can influence the way a wire glows than watt?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/349055/174208)

The question is clearly stated as

> So my question is, what electrical unit can influence this options, given that the power is set fix?

Whats unclear about that?

If there are any parameters, that can influence the way a coild would burn, I'm clearly asking for them, and if there aren't any other that would also be a valid answer.

How can I be more clear?!

Comment: Because the units don't affect the way a wire glows at all. The temperature of the wire determines how it glows. It doesn't matter whether we measure the temperature in farenheit, celsius, kelvin, or rankine degrees.

Comment: More precisely stated: it's the quantity (temperature) that matters, not the units we use to measure the quantity.

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear to us because the way you asked it makes it clear that you do not have the necessary background to understand any answer we might give in the terms that we normally use.

Since your question pertains to the use of a particular device, you would probably get a better response in some kind of forum in which other users of that type of device normally hang out. They would be able to explain the issue in terms that you understand.

Answer (score 2):

Pressure, gas, ambient temperature... In fact, all the ways Watts can disappear other than by optical band radiation